# Placement of plotly legend labels

Tags: r, plotly, label, legend

Plotly places legend labels to the right of their respective "boxes" by default. If possible, I would like to place the labels below the boxes.

I have produced a plotly figure with orientation = "h" to place the legend horizontally below the plot. However, as in the picture below, there isn't enough space to lay the legend and its labels out in one row.

```
answer <- c("Not satisfied", "Somewhat satisfied", "Satisfied", "Very satisfied", "Completely satisfied",
            "Not satisfied", "Somewhat satisfied", "Satisfied", "Very satisfied", "Completely satisfied",
            "Not satisfied", "Somewhat satisfied", "Satisfied", "Very satisfied", "Completely satisfied")

freq <- c(0.2, 0.18, 0.23, 0.16, 0.23, 0.24, 0.3, 0.20, 0.17, 0.09, 0.22, 0.18, 0.19, 0.25, 0.16)

group <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c")

data <- data.frame(answer, freq, group)
data$answer <- factor(data$answer, levels =c("Not satisfied", "Somewhat satisfied", "Satisfied", "Very satisfied", "Completely satisfied"))

plot_ly(data,
        y = ~group, 
        x = ~freq) %>%
  add_trace(
    color = ~answer, 
    type = "bar",
    showlegend = T) %>%
  layout(barmode = "relative",
         legend = list(orientation="h"),
         xaxis = list(title = ""))
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMQ7p.png)

I would like to save space by placing the labels below the legend "boxes", as in this example:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc9Sk.png)

I haven't found any relevant documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.